# WASP Node Instalation

Tags: iota-network

I am trying to set up the wasp node the first time, I am trying to follow the official tutorial but somehow cannot figure out How to install the wasp console or command line. I know this is a very basic question but if someone has some reference material then please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you need to install from source.
You can clone the [wasp repo](https://github.com/iotaledger/wasp) to get started.

Please follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eV2AoV3QPC4&list=PLMbc46iGTB_SCQ-Ut_c8__ssMDFUusVBJ&index=1&ab_channel=IOTAFoundation) around the same.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I am following the same tutorial my question is, DO I need to install the wasp separately?

Comment: When you're building from the repo, you're essentially installing it.

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube guide is not working after some updates. The GitHub repo also seems to have some errors. Can someone look at the repo and explain how the errors can be fixed?